# Replace android.support.v4.util.ArraySet with androidx.collection.ArraySet in Maven library

Tags: java, android, gradle, androidx

I have a 3rd party library that depends on:

`import android.support.v4.util.ArraySet;`

And I want to use the latest Android libraries in the rest of my project:

`import androidx.collection.ArraySet;`

However, since I'm getting the library via Maven, I can't seem to force it to replace the v4 dependency for the androidx one and have it refer to the right class.

I've already tried:

```
implementation 'androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0'
implementation('some-library:v1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

And:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.android.support:support-v4') with module('androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0')
    }
}
```

I've even tried a few more things including the `force=true` for the dependencies I want.

However I'm still getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArraySet;
```

How can I tell Gradle to resolve the imports for `android.support.v4.util.ArraySet` to `androidx.collection.ArraySet` when I don't have access to the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Migrate to AndroidX guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio):

> `android.enableJetifier=true`
>
> The Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries.

So this rewriting of Maven dependencies is exactly what Jetifier does for you. Make sure you've added the `android.enableJetifier=true` to your `gradle.properties` file to enable Jetifier.